# Azure SQL server from development to production

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I created an Azure SQL server and database on Azure portal, I want to connect this server from remote like we are team of 4 and work from home, plus we created a asp.net core microservices which are deployed to Azure App Services --> web app. We do not want to expose database publicly. Only developer should be able to access, and the Web app deployed under Azure App services. appreciate step or some good video or articles link on the approach to follow.
Thanks, and appreciate for any help and support.

Comment: This is off topic. Check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Server database can be accessible from your app service with the connection string and user/login credentials. You can mention the SQL server path in the connection string.

You can create the SQL user login with the Read/write roles.

You would also have to whitelist the IP address of the developers systems who are going to access the Az SQL server from the SSMS tool in their laptops.